# Can I mix ASC and PSC when analyzing a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Can I analyze any circuit using Active Sign Convention (ACS) for power sources and Passive Sign Convention (PSC) for resistors, or will this lead to errors? In other words, should I always stick to the same convention when analyzing a circuit?

Comment: Please show an example and define your acronyms

Comment: The acronyms are defined in the text of the question. This is a theoretical question (any circuit), so in principle examples shouldn't be needed to answer it.